# Multiple strict equality comparisons in a single line

Tags: javascript, types, equality

I have the following JavaScript code:

```
var a = 1;
var b = 1;
a === 1        // evaluates to true
b === 1        // evaluates to true
a == b == 1    // evaluates to true
a === b === 1  // evaluates to false
```

Why does `a === b === 1` evaluate to `false`?

Comment: Because `a === b` is `true` and `true` is not strictly equivalent to `1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a == b == 1
```

is evaluated as

```
((a == b) == 1)
```

Since `a == b` is `true`, the expression becomes

```
true == 1
```

Since `==` does type coercing, it converts `true` to a number, which becomes 1. So the expression becomes

```
1 == 1
```

That is why this expression is `true`. You can confirm the boolean to number conversion like this

```
console.log(Number(true));
// 1
console.log(Number(false));
// 0
```

---

Similarly,

```
a === b === 1
```

is evaluated as

```
((a === b) === 1)
```

so

```
true === 1
```

Since `===` doesn't do type coercion (as it is the [strict equality operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/359509/1903116)), this expression is `false`.